# 'Launch More like this' AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have a blog running on AWS EC2 `t2.micro`.

This `t2.micro` is getting out-scaled and I need a bigger instance. I'm hosting a Wordpress blog.

Is there a way to change in to `t2.medium` without affecting the downtime?

I was thinking about the 'Launch more like this' button. Will it launch 2 instances like I have? Where will my site be hosted then?

Comment: This is already supported. Down-time depends on what type of "storage" you are using? EBS backed or Instance-backed? If Instance-backed, you don't need to have any downtime. If EBS-backed, you need to have some down time.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

Comment: You also need to think about how you will handle replication, and keeping it in sync. If you have two t2 micro instances, then you will have two separate databases, two separate wordpress installs, which just happen to start off similar.

Comment: No. You cannot change the instance type without downtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Easiest solution:** Have some downtime.

- Stop the instance
- Change the Instance Type
- Start the instance

Do it when usage is low and it will have minimal impact. Only takes 1-2 minutes.

If a few minutes is too much downtime for you, then you should redesign the system as a Highly-Available application with multiple servers running in different Availability Zones, using a shared, multi-AZ database. If you are just running on one server, there is **no guarantee of uptime**.

Answer (score 1):

'Launch More Like This' will only help in creating a duplicate server with the same networking characteristics (security groups, volume sizing, etc.). It will not be an identical clone in terms of content unless your configuration is done entirely from the User Data or Cloud Init (which will be the same when you launch using the 'Launch More Like This' button, or if you are using Ansible/Chef or some other system to configure it after the fact. When you launch more like this, you are able to change the instance type if there is a path from your current instance type to the one you want (within any family, such as t2, this is almost always possible). Otherwise, you will have to stop and start the instance to do so.

If you're looking for high availability, you probably want to use an ELB with a Route 53 DNS record that corresponds to your website's URL backed by two instances where requests for the website can be served by either of a pair of instances.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this. When you change the instance type, AWS has to choose a different physical hardware. It may be on the same physical machine or (more likely) another physical machine. For this to happen, the instance has to be stopped before moving it to a new physical machine.

There is no concept of live motion like VMWare in AWS. Your instance has to be stopped before you can change its size.

`Launch more like this` will create another machine just like the current one. If you have an elastic IP attached, there will be a few seconds of downtime when you re-associate the elastic IP, but the new machine will be a clone of the old machine with a 
different private IP.

Answer (score 1):

**For 'Launch more like this' button:**
     If you use launch more like this button , the storage device will be changed and the data stored on it will be erased. so it will be new instance. you can not see your wordpress blog.

**Solution:** 
      Just create the AMI Image from your running instance and you should not click no reboot option(why because you may get errors while launching or after launching the new instance from the newly created image). After creating an image and launch with the type t2.medium and run the start the web server inside the instance then repoint your newly created instance ip to your DNS server.

Hopefully you will see your website at "new-instance-public-ip"

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new EC2, install the blog on it and attach a fixed IP with [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/route53/) and after that you can attach your domain to your new IP and then you can terminate the micro EC2.

Comment: If the instance cannot be scaled, then you don't need to install anything because you can just re-mount volume to the new instance